# What happens with an exception thrown within a ChannelFutureListener?

Tags: java, exception, netty

I assumed the exception would be processed as an upstream event in the pipeline of the channel but my stack trace doesn't look that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just gets logged via the InternalLogger, so no upstreamevent.